# Zeroary method with generic return type

Tags: scala, generics, types, casting

I have the following code which is supposed to be a factory class. Its apply method has a generic parameter for the return type restriction:

```
sealed trait Account
final case class CheckingAccount() extends Account
final case class SavingsAccount() extends Account

object Account {
    def apply[T <: Account]:T = {
        CheckingAccount()   // CheckingAccount().asInstanceOf[T]
    }
}
```

But compiler reports "Expression of type Banking.CheckingAccount doesn't conform to exected type T", if don't do type conversion explicitly. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Your method `apply` does not return a `SavingsAccount` if you invoke it as `Account.apply[SavingsAccount]`, so why should it typecheck?

Comment: That function body just an example, it might return anything subtype to Account.

Comment: If it might return any subtype of `Account`, then the return type should be `Account`. That's not what your function signature is telling in this example.

Comment: You mean the function signature can only declare the super type without any extra information about it's possible sub child information?

Comment: Lots of things are possible. But if you promise to return exactly the `T` that you are asked for, you cannot return a `CheckingAccount` when you are asked for a `SavingsAccount`. Therefore, your method doesn't typecheck. Moreover, it is easy to see that a method with signature `def apply[T <: Account]: T` *must* always throw an exception, because `Nothing <: Account`, and you guarantee that `Account.apply[Nothing]` will return a `Nothing`, which is impossible (unless you guarantee that your method never returns by throwing an exception or an error).

Comment: I see, so you mean if I promise a specific return type it should return, don't give any chance for client to name something else out of the scope.

Comment: This may be an X-Y-problem. Why do you want the client to name something else? What is the use-case? And how does the client tell the method what it wants to have? (The method certainly has to return what its type signature says it returns, it is a typesafe language after all)

Comment: Please put your answer to the post, thanks!

Comment: No, it is not an X-Y problem, it is what I mean, I just misunderstand with the return type of signature, in this case, return "CheckingAccount" is find, if client probably query something else, don't give  them object, instead of a trait, and let client to implement and define the return type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method signature

```
def apply[T <: Account]: T
```

guarantees that *for every* `T` that is a subtype of `Account` you can produce a `T`.

In particular,

```
Account.apply[Nothing]
```

should "return" an instance of `Nothing`. Since there are no instances of `Nothing`, the only way you can implement such a method is by throwing an error / exception. In other words, the signature of you method asks for so little and promises *so much*, that the method becomes effectively unimplementable.

---

#### Workaround 1

Remove the type argument. Return an `Account`.

---

#### Workaround 2

If you want to keep the generic return type, you might want to try something like this instead:

```
sealed trait Account
final case class CheckingAccount() extends Account
final case class SavingsAccount() extends Account

trait Default[X] {
  def createDefault: X
}

implicit object DefaultCheckingAccount extends Default[CheckingAccount] {
  def createDefault = CheckingAccount()
}

implicit object DefaultSavingsAccount extends Default[SavingsAccount] {
  def createDefault = SavingsAccount()
}

object Account {
    def apply[T <: Account](implicit d: Default[T]): T = d.createDefault
}

Account[SavingsAccount]
Account[CheckingAccount]
```

It compiles, but looks somewhat redundant (what's the point of calling `Account[SavingsAccount]` instead of just `SavingsAccount()`?)

Comment: Your answer kinds like assuming I'm asking X. But still good! I like this discussion! thanks!